# JSON Parsing a File of Standalone Objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I have a JSON file with discrete objects that are not enclosed in another composite object (e.g. an array).  The reason for this is that I don't want to rely on the assumption that they will all fit into memory.

In other words, I'd like to iterate over them, reading, parsing, and processing them one at a time.

In YAML I can do this using YAML.load_documents.  Is there such a thing in (Ruby) JSON?

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: I think I understand. An example in the question would be useful though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want a streaming parser for JSON.

Try [yajl-ruby](http://rubygems.org/gems/yajl-ruby), a gem with ruby bindings to the Yajl JSON streaming parser library, or [JSON::Stream](https://github.com/dgraham/json-stream) a streaming pure-ruby JSON parser.

Comment: Thanks!  I used yajl-ruby.  I couldn't find an example of handling parsed records one at a time, but came up with this method, which works for me: https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/5930475.

Comment: Don't forget the Oj gem.  It provides a significantly faster streaming JSON parser interface via Oj::ScHandler (simple callback handler).